# Recursive method that will compute the sum of the first n integers in an array of at least n integers. Begin with nth integer

Tags: java, recursion

This is my code so far but when I run it and enter a value for n the program ends with "Sum of numbers is: " and that's all. Doesn't change no matter what value I enter, can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class addNum
{
    //A method for Adding
    public static int addNum (int arr[], int n)
    {
      int x = 0;
      if (n > arr.length)
      {
          return 0;
      }
      else if (n == 1)
      {
          return 1;
      }
      else 
      {
         x = arr[n-1] + addNum(arr, n);
         return n;
      }
     }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n = 0;
        int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        System.out.println("Input your number and press enter: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Sum of numbers is:");
        addNum(arr, n);
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static int addNum (int arr[], int n)
        {
          int x = 0;
          if (n > arr.length)
          {
              return 0;
          }
          else if (n == 1)
          {
              //When n == 1, you want to return the first element of your array and not 1
              return arr[0];
          }
          else 
          {
             //As you go deeper into recursion, you break your problem into a smaller problem.
             //Therefore, when calling addNum again, you pass n-1 and not n, as now you want to add remaining n-1 numbers 
             x = arr[n-1] + addNum(arr, n-1);
             // you want to return your sum x and not n
             return x;
          }
         }

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int n = 0;
            int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
            System.out.println("Input your number and press enter: ");
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            n = in.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Sum of numbers is:");
            //Your addNum method returns an int, so you want to save it in a variable and then print it 
            int x = addNum(arr, n);
            System.out.println(x);
            }
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat you missed one bug

Comment: it is not a bug, the first element of `arr` is `1` but I accept your point

Comment: No, I meant `x = arr[n-1] + addNum(arr, n-1);`  Passing n-1 to addNum instead of n

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh Yes! That worked, I did fix my code with arr[0] for when n==1, after I realized that the first value of the array wont always be 1 but your code helped me clear up the rest of errors. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

try changing it to

```
    System.out.println(addNum(arr, n));
```

so something is actually returned and printed

and there is a bug

```
x = arr[n-1] + addNum(arr, n);
return x;  // not n
```

Answer (score 1):

```
addNum(arr, n);
```

This is just a function call addNum(param1, param2).

It will only be returning value, not printing out value. 
Thus, you have to print that value out in order to be able to see it.

> `System.out.println(addNum(arr, n));`

As mentioned by Siren P. will work